# Matching when an arbitrary pattern appears multiple times

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will succeed when an arbitrary pattern of length 2 or greater appears more than once in a phrase. Essentially, I would like to use a capture group in the search.

Something like this, but generalized to match any phrase, not just `foo`

```
/foo.*foo/
```

For example,

**Should match:**

```
abcdabcd     ('abcd' is repeated)
foobarfoo    ('foo' is repeated)
mathematics  ('mat' is repeated)
```

**Should not match:**

```
bar        (no repetition of any pattern)
foo        ('o' is repeated but it is not length>=2)
```

Can regexes do this? Or should I be using something else?

Comment: with `mathematics` you can match `ma` or `at` twice - I think most solutions will give you the first in preference to the second - just sayin'

Comment: You're right. I didn't notice that. I updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: Good edit of question as my answer was already matching `mat` in `mathematics`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
(.{2,})(?=.*?\1)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vO3uN4/1)

**Explanation:**

```
.{2,}     # any 2 or more characters
(.{2,})   # group them into captured group #1
(?=...)   # positive lookahead
(?=.*?\1) # make sure at least one occurrence of captured group #1
```

Comment: You're so close! Your current answer doesn't give matches over 2 characters in length - so `abcd` is not picked up for example. The regex needs to be `(.{2,})(?=.*?\1)` - feel free to use =)

Comment: Ah good point and sorry for my silly mistake. It is fixed now.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks! What is the `\1` called? My attempts at looking up "capture group in search pattern" turned up useless. Also, regex101.com seems a lot nicer than the other testers I have been using!

Comment: `\1` is back-reference to captured group #1 so in words it makes sure we have at least one repeat of 2+ character set.